# Observable takeUntil misbehaving

Tags: scala, rx-java

I'm trying to implement a helper method on observables that returns a new observable emitting only the values until a timeout is reached:

```
implicit class ObservableOps[T](obs: Observable[T]) {

  def timedOut(totalSec: Long): Observable[T] = {
    require(totalSec >= 0)
    val timeOut = Observable.interval(totalSec seconds)
      .filter(_ > 0)
      .take(1)
    obs.takeUntil(timeOut)
  }
}
```

I wrote a test for it, which creates an observable emitting its first value long after the timeout. However, the resulting observable still seems to include the late value:

```
test("single value too late for timeout") {
  val obs = Observable({Thread.sleep(8000); 1})
  val list = obs.timedOut(1).toBlockingObservable.toList
  assert(list === List())
}
```

The test fails with the message `List(1) did not equal List()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of rx-java are you using?

Comment: @Dimitri rxjava-scala-0.15.0 and I can't upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `Thread.sleep(8000)` is actually blocking your main thread. Did you try to add a println after `val obs` in your test to see if it appears right after the test starts?

What's happening here is that your declaration of `obs` blocks your program for 8 seconds, *then* you create your new observable using `timedOut`, such that `timedOut` see the emitted value as soon as it's called.

Using `rx-scala` 0.23.0 your `timedOut` method works (excepted that Observable.interval doesn't emit immediately so the `filter(_ > 0)` should be removed).

```
val obs = Observable.just(42).delay(900.millis)
val list = obs.timedOut(1).toBlocking.toList
println(list) // prints List(42)

val obs = Observable.just(42).delay(1100.millis)
val list = obs.timedOut(1).toBlocking.toList
println(list) // prints List()
```